# How many rails instances does delayed job initialize if running multiple pools

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I'm running Delayed Job with the pool option like:

```
bundle exec bin/delayed_job -m --pool=queue1 --pool=queue2 start
```

Will this spawn one OR multiple rails instances? (ie: will it spawn one instance for all the pools or will every pool get its own rails instance)?

When testing locally it seemed to only spawn one rails instance for all the pools.

But I want to confirm this 100% (esp on production).

I tried using commands like these to see what the DJ processes were actually pointing to:

```
ps aux, lsof, pstree
```

Anyone know for sure how this works, or any easy way to find out? I started digging through the source code but figured someone prob knows a quicker way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should spawn multiple processes, not sure why you're seeing only one.

From [the readme](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#running-jobs):

> Use the `--pool` option to specify a worker pool. You can use this option multiple times to start different numbers of workers for different queues.
>   The following command will start 1 worker for the tracking queue, 2 workers for the mailers and tasks queues, and 2 workers for any jobs:
>
> ```
> RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --pool=tracking --pool=mailers,tasks:2 --pool=*:2 start
> ```

#### Further details after discussion in comments

The question mentions "Rails instances", but *instance* is a generic term. The word you're looking for is [*process*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)). The text quoted from DelayedJob's readme uses the word *worker*, short for *worker process*. In Rails, you usually refer to server processes as just *servers*, and to worker processes as just *workers*.
The `rails console`, too, is just another process.

In Rails all these processes will load the whole application, but will do different things.
*Server* processes will wait for incoming HTTP requests and send back responses; *worker* processes will periodically poll a queue (DelayedJob uses the DB) and execute jobs; the *console* process will start a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) and wait for input.
They will all have access to the same code (models, DB config, assets, view template, etc), but will have very different responsibilities.

I hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: Not seeing the answer in that readme. It is running multiple workers as it should. The question is: does it fire up one rails enviroment and then run the multiple workers within that; OR does every worker (pool) get its own rails environment.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by _environment_. Rails' default environments are `development`, `test`, `production`, plus any you define. Rails processes (server or delayed_job workers) select an environment when they start.

Comment: Or do you mean environment as "execution context"? POSIX processes are independent, and don't normally share data or talk with each other.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I mean how many rails instances are running for each delayed job queue. For example if I run "rails console" 5 times then it'll load 5 rails instances.

Comment: Ok, then my answer is the right one. Will add details to the answer to explain.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this. Think there's a misunderstanding. I'll provide more details in a separate answer above, but  after looking through the code, it only spawns one rails process for all the worker pools.

Answer (score 0):

After digging through the code the short answer is..

**Running something like this:**

```
bundle exec bin/delayed_job -m --pool=queue1 --pool=queue2 start
```

**will start ONE rails process/instance for ALL the pools/queues you specify.**

---

Details below if you want more explanation:

In the Command class:

this loops through and setups up the workers:

```
 def setup_pools
  worker_index = 0
  @worker_pools.each do |queues, worker_count|
    options = @options.merge(:queues => queues)
    worker_count.times do
      process_name = "delayed_job.#{worker_index}"
      run_process(process_name, options)
      worker_index += 1
    end
  end
end
```

Which will run this for each queue:

```
def run(worker_name = nil, options = {})
  Dir.chdir(root)

  Delayed::Worker.after_fork
  Delayed::Worker.logger ||= Logger.new(File.join(@options[:log_dir], 'delayed_job.log'))

  worker = Delayed::Worker.new(options)
  worker.name_prefix = "#{worker_name} "
  worker.start
```

Each worker is daemonized, but there aren't new rails processes started. It just loops through each pool/queue in its own daemon.

You can see this in the "start" method:

```
def start
     loop do
      self.class.lifecycle.run_callbacks(:loop, self) do
        @realtime = Benchmark.realtime do
          @result = work_off
        end
      end
```

If you want to start a rails instance for each new queue you could use monit and do something like:

```
check process delayed_job_0
  with pidfile /var/www/apps/{app_name}/shared/pids/delayed_job.0.pid
  start program = "/usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=production /var/www/apps/{app_name}/current/bin/delayed_job start -i 0"
  stop program = "/usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=production /var/www/apps/{app_name}/current/bin/delayed_job stop -i 0"
  group delayed_job

check process delayed_job_1
  with pidfile /var/www/apps/{app_name}/shared/pids/delayed_job.1.pid
  start program = "/usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=production /var/www/apps/{app_name}/current/bin/delayed_job start -i 1"
  stop program = "/usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=production /var/www/apps/{app_name}/current/bin/delayed_job stop -i 1"
  group delayed_job
```